# Create RAID1 from existing drive and a blank

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid1

I have a Dell Precision t1650 machine with an existing in-use hard drive and an empty hard drive bay. I have a brand new hard drive (same size and manufacturer as the original), and I'd like to setup redundant RAID1 (no parity, striping, or spanning). The motherboard supports hardware raid.

Can I boot into a live CD, clone the existing drive onto the blank, then enable RAID1 in the BIOS and have it "just work" without losing anything that's already on the drive?

Comment: "A Dell machine" is casting a large net. Can you be more specific? A model number might help a lot.

Comment: Dell Precision t1650

Comment: I guess the lack of answers to this question demonstrate why we don't love hardware RAID.

Comment: @MadHatter interesting. is software RAID more flexible? i always assumed software RAID was next-best-thing for people who don't have a hardware RAID controller.

Comment: Not from where I stand.  For a simple RAID-1 setup, mdadm RAID is much simpler, easier to work with, and more transparent to monitor, than any hardware RAID I've ever met.  For a 12-disc RAID-6 array with NVRAM write cache, sure, hardware RAID is worth the considerable overhead.  But for simple RAID setups I'll take mdadm any day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Dell Precision T1650 in particular, the RAID controller does not support creating a new RAID array without losing all data on both disks.